# How to force IFrames to not share js resource thread with parent frame with same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser

In my application, i have an iFrame component with same domain as the parent but with different path.

**Example:**
My application runs in "abc.xyz.com" domain.
The iFrame in the application have the url "abc.xyz.com/application1" (this is different application having same domain)

Since the parent and iFrame having same domain the javascript resource thread is common for both. I have multiple iFrames like this with same domain name. This causes some performance issues.

Is there any way to force iFrame to use different js thread even-though the same domain is loaded.(like loading in new tab)?

PS: The iFrame and parent strictly needs to have same domain for some reasons and don't want to use cross-domains.

Comment: It's not because of the same domain. It's because it how it always works

Comment: KS  always uses only one thread except for web workers

Comment: There is a chrome flag `chrome://flags/#enable-isolated-sandboxed-iframes`  that unleashes site isolation from a simply sandboxed iframe, even if they actually shared the same origin before the sandbox (but not if there is `allow-same-origin`, obviously since then they should be able to communicate synchronously).

Comment: @Kaiido `Origin-Agent-Cluster` HTTP header will not request separate resources for the iframe when it's the same origin, just when it's different origins from the same site it allocates separate resource.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I misread. Back to the experimental flag (which is also cited in the linked Q/A.